# Using variables in constructing new labels

Tags: labels

First, apologies for my lack of knowledge in this matter. I am trying the following code without really understanding every bit and piece of it.

Anyway, can anyone help me find what is wrong with the following code?

```
\def\pm #1#2{\@bsphack
\newcommand{\currentValue}{\ref{#1}}
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
  {\string\newlabel{test\currentValue}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
\@esphack}
```

My intentions? To define a `\pm` command that takes two arguments.
The first argument needs to be used as a reference itself in order to obtain another variable: `\currentValue`.
Then, this variable (`\currentValue`) is appended to some other text ('test') in order to create a new label.

Things look good, but for some reason, when the final label is created, an `\hbox {}` is appended to the end of the `test\currentValue` label.

Any idea what the problem is? Or how can I achieve my goal, if not in this manner?

Comment: `\ref{key}` is a command to *print* something. If can contain boxes or font commands. It is normally not suitable as part of the key of a label. You could try the `zref` package. With it you can define reference commands which gives back "pure" values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd obtain the same without the `\newcommand{\currentValue}{\ref{#1}}`: your code is equivalent to

```
\def\pm #1#2{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
  {\string\newlabel{test\ref{#1}}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
\@esphack}
```

because the expansion of `\currentValue` would be exactly `\ref{#1}` (with the actual argument to `\pm` in place of `#1`).

Here is the problem: `\protected@write` is unable to get the *value* of `\ref{#1}`, because this requires performing assignments which are *never* performed in a write operation.

You may have better luck with

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\def\pm #1#2{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
  {\string\newlabel{test\getrefnumber{#1}}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
\@esphack}
```

but it's unclear what you want to achieve here, because you'll need to know the value of `\ref{foo}` in order to refer to the label generated by

```
\pm{foo}{bar}
```

(assuming you have a `\label{foo}` somewhere). So the generate label can be `test1` if `\ref{foo}` gives "1", but when `\ref{foo}` changes also the generated *label* will change.

*Note* `\pm` is a command of the LaTeX kernel, redefine it at your own risk.

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks, it works. `\getrefnumber`is what I needed, instead of `\ref`.  Also, thanks for noting that `\pm`is already a command of the LaTeX kernel.